# Посчитать количество определенного html тэга на странице с помощью php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не могу сообразить задача код на php: 
на входе стринг с html кодом и html тэг; 
на выходе количество указанного тега на странице например для кода.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script src="sendvox.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

тэгов body 1 шт, тэгов meta 3 шт. и т.д. Есть идеи?

Comment: 'preg_match_all(
        '/<\s*html[^>]*>(.*?)/',
        '<!DOCTYPE html> <html class="no-js" lang="en"><head>',
      $matches
      );
      echo '<pre>';
      print_r($matches);'
такой код не работает... что не так?

Comment: '~</?html[^>]*>~'

Comment: @Эдуард выводит следующий результат:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

)

Comment: если закрывающие парные теги не нужно подсчитывать: **[смотреть пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0beaeff15b9d6322dae458a1e3e3c63651f86a1c)**

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем решение нашел.

```
$tag='div'; // или любой тэг какой недо

$str='/<\s*'.$tag.'[^>]*>(.*?)/';

      preg_match_all($str,$output,$matches);// $output cтрока с html

      $numbOfElemens=count($matches[0]);// количество тэгов на странице
```

Comment: Тогда еще проще: `<TagName.*?>`.